# Show content depending on Document Mode

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9

Is there a way to show on a web page which browser mode and which document mode is set?

Is this generally possible and is it possible to show/hide some content depending of which mode is switched on?

I would like to use a function to allow upload by drag and drop (see http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) but I noticed that this works only when IE is in a specific Document Mode. In case this mode is not switched on I would like to disable the Option to upload by drag and drop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
j(document).ready(function(){
    /* detect usage of IE Developer Tools using different Mode for Browser and Document */
    if(j.browser.msie) {
        var browserVersion = j.browser.version.slice(0,j.browser.version.indexOf("."));
        var documentVersion = document.documentMode;
        if(browserVersion != documentVersion) {
            alert("ERROR:\nBrowser Mode and Document Mode do not match!\n\nBrowser Mode: IE"+ browserVersion +".0\nDocument Mode: IE"+ documentVersion +".0");
        }
    }
});
```

Courtesy: http://my.opera.com/Schalandra/blog/2012/02/29/how-to-detect-different-browser-mode-and-document-mode-in-ie

Maybe you'll find this answer helpful too.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/623071/903454

Answer (score 1):

You can detect the document-mode:

```
var mode = document.documentMode;
```

If the mode is Internet Exlporer 5, it returns five, if it's IE6, it returns 6, and so on.

However, you can force a specific document mode:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=[IEVersion]">
```

Where [IEVersion] is one of the following:

- **Edge** Always the newest version
- **EmulateIE9** If the doctype is set, the mode is IE9, otherwise IE5
- **EmulateIE8** See *EmulateIE9*
- **EmulateIE7** See *EmulateIE9*
- **9** Alway IE9
- **8** Always IE8
- **7** Always IE7
- **5** Always IE5

PS: Your plugin should recognize the mode automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use document.documentMode in IE to find out html document

- 5 The page is displayed in IE5 mode
- 7 The page is displayed in IE7mode
- 8 The page is displayed in IE8 mode
- 9 The page is displayed in IE9 mode